# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.BCException in JBOSS AS

Tags: java, maven, jboss, aspectj, spring-aop

Currently, my application server does not start because it reports class not found when my dependencies are already exposed in the maven and bundled together in my ear.

Basically how do you get JBOSS 7.1 to work with AspectJ smoothly.

Maybe I need to add a module? An AspectJ module?

Any advice will be great.

More Details about the error

```
01:18:41,515 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (MSC service thread 1-7) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/BCException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:159) [spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Did you check if aspectjweaver-<version>.jar is in your classpath (through JBoss, your EAR file)?

Comment: Yes. It's definitely in my ear. But my JBOSS deployment structure bootstraps Spring AOP modules early in the lifecycle. So I have to include the aspectjweaver even before the any war sub deployment starts. I will share my results soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my app server is loaded with a predefined list of modules from Spring. I had to override it with my own.

An example is shown below.

```xml
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.springframework.spring">

<resources>
    <resource-root path="spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="aopalliance-1.0.jar"/> <!-- added -->
    <resource-root path="cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar"/> <!-- added --> 
    <resource-root path="aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar"/> <!-- added -->
    <resource-root path="aspectjweaver-1.6.11.jar"/> <!-- added -->
</resources>

<dependencies>
   ...
</dependencies>

</module>
```